# C# Is there "Ternary-style" Exception Handling?

Tags: c#, exception, conditional-operator

I sometimes run into situations where, if a line of code throws an exception, I don't care what the exception is or why it was thrown; I just need to take a generic action and move on.  For example:

```
        try
        {
            // Throws IndexOutOfRangeException when DB field 
            // is null in the current record
            Template = record.GetString(MYSQL_IDX_TEMPLATE);
        }
        catch
        {
            Template = FIELD_UNAVAILABLE;
        }
```

I was wondering if there's a short-hand way to set a value based on a generic try/catch?

I'm thinking of something similar to ternary syntax:

```
string blah = (index >= ubound ? "No more records" : "records exist");
```

Comment: Catching all exceptions, then ignoring the exception object itself and assuming that a specific one was the one thrown usually isn’t a good idea. In the case you showed, for example, you should probably use exactly that: a comparison of `MYSQL_IDX_TEMPLATE` against the size of `record`.

Comment: In your code the catch clause should be changed to catch(Exception ex).

Comment: @VictorHavin why? The variable wouldn't be used.

Comment: @Ry- MYSQL_IDX_TEMPLATE is a string not an int.  This code block is hit half a million times.  I just want to mark it as unavailable and move on to the next record.

Comment: Not caring about the exception type, the details or the exception nor using the exception variable is very rare. There's not much value in having a shorthand syntax for something that's very rare.

Comment: It's bad practice to use exceptions for program flow. Exceptions should be exceptional. It's clear, better and more performance to do checks that ensure you don't get exceptions

Comment: If there existed an operator form for exceptions (more like the null coalescing `??` perhaps) it would just be syntactic sugar for the traditional `try`...`catch` and not speed anything up. You could write a generic (extension?) method that was slower, however.

Comment: Few reasons: 1. Since you do not rethrow, you consume exceptions, thus changing  code behavior outside your method. 2. It is bad practice (see comment from Dave). 3. It is uncommon. If you do not care about exception, why implement try/catch? Exceptions are expensive.